# $.trim space using $.trim doesn't work in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $(".p").each(function(i){
          len=$(this).text().length;
          if(len>80)
          {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,80)+'...');
          }
        });
```

some of my output is fine like

```
abc def...
```

but some of it will be like

```
1234 45 ...
```

How to trim the space? I tried $.trim but doesn't work.

Comment: You can trim the left or right spaces but not the middle ones.

Comment: `$.trim` should work. Show what you tried.

Comment: I think he just wants to get rid of the spaces immediately before `...`, not in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".p").text(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length > 80) {
        return $.trim(text.substr(0, 80)) + '...';
    } else {
        return text;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! using each in my case is not necessary right? and the last } should be });

Comment: When you give a function argument to `.text()`, it does its own looping, so you don't need to use `.each()`